# Angular Material filtrar Tabla desde otro componente

Tags: angular, angular-material

Buenas noches comunidad!

Acá dejo mi primer pregunta a ver si alguien me puede dar una mano.
Estoy trabajando con Angular Material en una app de Contactos, estos vienen de un archivo .json que trabaja como base de datos.
Necesito filtrar los contactos que se muestran en mi tabla, pero quiero hacerlo desde otro componente donde tengo armado el input.
Leí la documentación de Material pero veo que lo trabaja desde el mismo componente donde está la tabla y no lo puedo hacer andar desde otro componente.

Les dejo el código:

Componente tabla

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Contacto } from '../../interface/contacto.interface';
import { ContactosService } from '../../services/contactos-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabla',
  templateUrl: './tabla.component.html',
  styles: [`
    table {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
  `]
})
export class TablaComponent implements OnInit {

  contactos: Contacto[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['nombre', 'apellido', 'telefono', 'empresa'];

  contacto = new MatTableDataSource(this.contactos)

  constructor(private _contactoService: ContactosService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getContactos()
  }

  getContactos() {
    this._contactoService.getContactos()
    .subscribe(resp => {
      this.contactos = resp;
    })
  }


}
```

Se agradece la ayuda!